# Any libraries to auto populate a CLR object

Tags: .net, clr

Anyone know of any libraries that can autopopulate a CLR object?

Ex:

I have a User object with first name and last name as members. I would
want to auto populate the object with some random values so the user
object can be used right away.

```
User user = new User ();

// Explicit member assignment
user.setFirstName ("John");
user.setLastName ("Doe");
```

// I need this

```
AutoPopulateLibrary.fill (user);
```

I'll pass the user object or the class name or whatever and the target
object must be magically filled.

Can this be done, or Am i missing something here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any tools to populate class properties with random data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413342/are-there-any-tools-to-populate-class-properties-with-random-data)

Answer (score 3):

This was asked before - there are some good answers:

- [Are there any tools to populate class properties with random data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413342/are-there-any-tools-to-populate-class-properties-with-random-data)
- [Populate a c# object with random values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361066/populate-a-c-object-with-random-values)
- [Get random data using Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177835/c-get-random-data-using-generics)

Answer (score 0):

None of @Oded's cited posts mention [Constrained Nondeterminism](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/03/05/ConstrainedNonDeterminism.aspx) as embodied by [AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com), which is a powerful force for simplifying tests, including the autogeneration of data.